# Bootstrap 4 pills is not working as expected in Angular6

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li [class.active]="viewMode=='map'" class="nav-item"><a (click)="viewMode='map'" class="nav-link">Map View</a></li>
    <li [class.active]="viewMode=='list'" class="nav-item"><a (click)="viewMode='list'" class="nav-link">List View</a></li>
</ul>
<div [ngSwitch]="viewMode">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'map'">Map View Content</div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'list'">List View Content</div>
    <div *ngSwitchDefault>Otherwise</div>
</div>
```

I want to have nav bar but bootstrap is not working as expected, I am getting outut like image in the following link
[It should be with blue background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krYSl.jpg)

Comment: Have you added bootstrap styles ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jmertm)

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a [class.active]="viewMode=='map'" (click)="viewMode='map'" class="nav-link">Map View</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a [class.active]="viewMode=='list'" (click)="viewMode='list'" class="nav-link">List View</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div [ngSwitch]="viewMode">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'map'">Map View Content</div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'list'">List View Content</div>
    <div *ngSwitchDefault>Otherwise</div>
</div>
```